# Deploy an existing app in Openshift

Tags: openshift

I created an web app and i d like to deploy in on Openshift. 
What s the easiest way to do it? I m using the Openshift Eclipse client.

Shall I create a new openshift and then copy all the files from the my exisitng app or is there are an easier way to covnert my existing app to an openshift one?

thnx

Comment: In which language did you create your web-app? OpenShift handles the directories for each given language differently. With more details we could perhaps work this one out.

Answer (score 4):

If your app is a Java EE web app, try this:

- http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com.br/2011/08/deploy-java-ee-application-on-openshift.html
- https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/express/how-can-i-deploy-a-war

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way to use OpenShift is through the rhc command line in combination with git.  Once you're setup you can easily git push to OpenShift and control your application's deployment with action hooks.  Check out an OpenShift example with a Python Django app: https://github.com/openshift/django-example
and the action hooks you can find here: https://github.com/openshift/django-example/tree/master/.openshift/action_hooks

Depending on what kind of app you're setting up, the process may differ slightly.  I suggest finding the OpenShift example for the type of application you're building (Java, Python, Ruby or w/e) on the OpenShift github https://github.com/openshift, get it going with their setup instructions and then move your code into the project.  Using the rhc command line and the starter repos to setup the project provides you with basic action hooks and git flow quickly.

If you're set on using the Eclipse client then follow along with this guide for deployment: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-eclipse-paas-integration

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Htd9vAxJAc),it shows you how to configure a openshift project (a new or a existing one) and then generate a ssh key for your app,you can manually copy/paste the ssh key to the openshift website,or the eclipse plug in will do it..

Answer (score 1):

Hi Below is the steps to create application by using eclipse:

Step 1 : Download the JBOSS tool from the following URL
http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/juno/
Step 2 : Sign up for an OpenShift Account
If you don’t already have an OpenShift account, head on over to the openshift website and click on signup. It is completely free and Red Hat gives every user three free Gears on which to run your applications. At the time of this writing, the combined resources allocated for each user is 1.5 GB of memory and 3 GB of disk space.
Step 3 : Creating SSH Keys
The next step is to create a RSA key to deploy the sample application. To create keys follow the steps mentioned below.
1.  Access the menu: Window> Preferences
2.  With the preferences window still open, go to: General> Network Connection> SSH
3.  Click on Tab Key Management and then the button Generate RSA Key …
4.  Copy the code key
5.  Now click the Save Private Key , then Ok as image below

Step 4: Adding a new SSH key to OpenShift
After creating the ssh keys, the next step is to upload the public keys generated in previous step to OpenShift .Go to openshift setting tab and add a new ssh key as shown below. You can find the public key in .ssh folder under your user home directory. The file will have a name id_rsa.pub. You can add multiple keys like one for your office and one for your home.

Step 5 : Create OpenShift Account Namespace
Every account needs to have one namespace which should be unique to the account only. One account can have only one namespace. Namespace form the part of the url that OpenShift assigns to an application. For example, if you application name is calba1 and namespace is backpain1, then the url of application will be http://xyz-abc.rhcloud.com. To create a namespace go to https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/settings and under namespace session enter the namespace.

Step 6 : Creating OpenShift Application
After creating the namespace, we are ready to create applications using JBoss Tools OpenShift support. Go to your eclipse and click File > New > Other> OpenShift Application as shown below and click next.

After pressing ‘Next’, you will be asked to provide your OpenShift credentials you created in step 3. If you have not signed up on OpenShift, you can click the sign up here link on the wizard to create your OpenShift account. Check the ‘Save password’ checkbox so that you don’t have to enter password with every command and click ‘Next’.

Next you will be asked to enter the details of the application like name of the application, type of the application, gear profile(whether you want small instance or medium instance.For FreeShift users,you can only create small instances), scaled application or non scaled application, and whether you want to embed any or multiple cartridges like mysql, postgresql, mongodb etc. We will create an application named springmvc3 of type jbosseap-6.0 and embed postgresql-8.4 cartridge.

Next you will be asked to configure your project and server adapter settings. Choose the default and click next.

The next screen will ask you to specify the location where you want to clone the git repository and name of the git remote.

Finally press the finish button and you are done. This will create an application container for us, called a gear, and setup all of the required SELinux policies and cgroup configuration. OpenShift will also setup a private git repository for you and clone the repository to your local system. Next, OpenShift will propagate the DNS to outside world. Finally, the project will be imported in your eclipse workspace. A new project will be created.

Step 6 : Exporting data to cloud database
Download RUBY software for running openshift commands from your local system. After downloading ruby open command prompt for ruby and run following command
rhc setup
After running this command please provide openshift credentials like user name and password. This command will connect you from Openshift. After successful connection you need to forward the ports on your system so you can connect  with Openshift databse from your system. Here is the following commands for port forwading.
rhc port-forward  
After you run this command you can connect with Openshift data base from your system. Run database script in the Openshift database for exporting all the data in Openshift cloud database. Terminate connection when you are finished with database by pressing CTRL+C.

Step 7 : Change database connections
Change your database credentials in your application by Openshift database  credentials. You can check the database credentials inside the application you have created in openshift.

Step 8 : Committing the code and Pushing to Cloud
To commit your code, ##Right click on project> Team>Commit.## Next it will ask you to enter commit message, so please enter any logical message.

Step 9 : Run your application
Now you are ready to run your application. Right click on project click on>Run as> and choose the openshift server to run. Now your application is live you can access it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The Openshift Eclipse plugin takes care of the process of creating an Openshift Gear, deploying your application and adding any cartridge you may want to use.
So, basically you just need to have your Openshift Online credentials handy.

Answer (score 0):

You could import it from DockerHub. You can install an app from DockerHub using:

`oc new-app docker.io/<repo>/<app-name>`