# How to host local create django project in openshift?

Tags: django, openshift

I have created a local-host Django 1.6 web application in my Ubuntu machine.Now I need to host this application in openshift.i tried but file structure is different.How can I host my Django project in openshift?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times before, e.g. [Deploy an existing app in Openshift](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19751440/3246440). There are some quickstarts available at github, most notably [openshift/django-example](https://github.com/openshift/django-example).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploy an existing app in Openshift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954161/deploy-an-existing-app-in-openshift)