# How to import existing projects from Open shift to the Eclipse?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, openshift

I have created the Java project in the Openshift 3.0. But i need to import the project into eclipse, I have read some documents regarding importing the project and got information, but one thing I did not get. [Please go through the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xk4J.png)

In this snapshot, i need to know what should i need to fill in the "Server" field. I did not get what actually the Openshift server url. If anyone know please guide me.

Comment: You should take a look to the following documentation : https://developers.openshift.com/getting-started/eclipse.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy an existing app in Openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954161/deploy-an-existing-app-in-openshift)

Comment: @MickaëlB, But i am not getting Screen in eclipse like as you mentioned in the document.